# What is wrong with dynamically adding listview column in android?

Tags: android, listview

I want generate 30 column or maybe more in listview, I do like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.liv);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> sourceList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<String> from=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> to = new ArrayList<>();
    int colNumber=30;
    int rowNumber=30;
    LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    for(int i=0;i<colNumber;i++) {
        from.add("col" + i);
        TextView textView=new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(textView);
        to.add(textView.generateViewId());
    }
    for(int j=0;j<rowNumber;j++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < colNumber; i++) {
            map.put("col" + i, i+","+j);
        }
        sourceList.add(map);
    }
    SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,sourceList, layout.getId(),from.toArray(new String[from.size()]),Utils.ToIntsArray(to));
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

but the layout.getId() is "-1", then I don't know how to generate effective layout resource id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not call generateViewId() on layout.

```
layout.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

But doesnt SimpleAdapter need a TextView Ressource?

You maybe could use [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) instead of ListView. I think it would be easier. Furthermore GridView would care about your cell sizes. With your code the cell widths would be different for each cell depending on your textlength.

Comment: I modify the program by setId, but it will closed and not throw exception, I think the TextView has been new `TextView textView=new TextView(this);` I'm in learning...

Comment: You maybe could use GridView instead of ListView.

Comment: But could you tell me why it doesn't work? If I use the xml resource id,then it will be created correctly.I mean if i write 30 textview in layout xml

Comment: No sry `layout.setId(View.generateViewId());` is the only thing i saw

Comment: If I write my program like this `SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, sourceList,  
                R.layout.liv_item, new String[] { "col1", "col2" },  
                new int[] {R.id.col1,R.id.col2}); `, and just put "col1" and "col2" in map, so the two method are different? and What are the different reasons?